# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 prevent close as won with javascript

Tags: javascript, crm, microsoft-dynamics

What is the javascript to prevent a user from closing an opportunity as won in crm 2011/2013? If the user wants to close as lost, I want to let them do it. But under certain conditions, I do not want them to close as won if a field is not populated. The CRM 4.0 code no longer works. I have the pass context as first parameter for the onsave event, no issues there, the code for

```
ExecutionObj.getEventArgs().getSaveMode()
```

works and returns a 5 when the opportunity is Closed and

```
 ExecutionObj.getEventArgs().preventDefault(); return false;
```

stops the save & close event (I have this part working) but how do I check for Close as Won (as opposed to Close as Lost)?